# Referencing a Numeric Value in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

How do you reference a numeric User input number in ModelBuilder?  I built a ModelBuilder tool that creates a traffic map based on a users input.  One question is between what two speeds is the traffic going?  So I need to select everything above one speed and below another......

In Select by attribute I tried `Speed>%MinSpeed%` but it did not work.

Both the user input variable and field type are 'double'.

The one possibility that just occurred to me is the numbers I have been using as user input numbers are whole numbers however the real data has it down to the decimal place. Would that effect anything? So user input is 20 and real data could be 20.05.

Comment: I built a ModelBuilder tool that creates a traffic map based on a users input. One question is between what two speeds is the traffic going? So I need to select everything above one speed and below another.

Comment: Select by Attribute

Comment: When you say, 'it did not work', what do you mean?  What happened that you didn't expect to happen?  What did not happen that you expected to happen?  What error message did you get (exact text)?  Please be very specific.  It may be worth posting some of your data here and a screenshot of your tool configuration.  No, a whole number input of `20` should compare fine against a decimal value of `20.5`.

Comment: In the layer used as input to the 'Select Layer by Attributes', is there already a selection?  I have found that ArcMap tools in model builder do not always work as expected when using layers that already have a selection on them, even when using the 'NEW_SELECTION' setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my expression was solid but I had the wrong number format. I simply rounded them both to a whole number and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to have some more detail in your question (eg, a screenshot of your 'Select Layer By Attribute' tool configuration in your model).

However, it works fine as follows in the 'Expression' field of the 'Select Layer by Attribute' tool in model builder for me:

```
Speed > %MinSpeed% AND Speed < %MaxSpeed%
```

(The question has been edited such that the information below may no longer be relevant to the updated question...)

NB:  **No quotes around the `%MinSpeed%`**.  Single quotes are required for a string literal, but should not be used for a number.  If you do use quotes, it will interpret the value as a string, not a number (which either won't work at all, or won't behave as expected).

Remember that the value qualified by the percent symbols will be substituted for the actual value when the SQL code is evaluated.  So when run, it will actually be evaluating something like:

```
Speed > 20 AND Speed < 60
```

You don't want to use quotes and evaluate something like:

```
Speed > '20' AND Speed < '60'
```

(Which would not make sense.)